# Android Sqlite java.lang.nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am using SQLite in Android eclipse, however it gives me a java.lang.nullpointerexception in the function createEntry. I tried using Questoid SQLite manager to view the database file and it does show up with the table created. Where's the bug?

```
public class Transact {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_TAG = "saved_tag";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabaseName";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tagsTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(
                    "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TAG + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }

    public Transact(Context c ){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Transact open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new    DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String tagword) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TAG, tagword);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, "", cv);
    }

    public String getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TAG};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iTag = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG);
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
         result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iTag) + "\n";     
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Code for the add button from Main.java class:

```
case R.id.addDB:

    boolean doneAdd = true;
    try{
        String tag = textTag.getText().toString();
        Transact entry = new Transact(Main.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(tag);
        entry.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Error");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
        doneAdd = false;
    }finally{
        if(doneAdd){
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Addition done");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Success");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: `NullPointerException`, on what line number?

Comment: The exception was occuring at `return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, "", cv);`
Solved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `ourDatabase` variable without initializing it. So not only insert you will get `nullpointerexception` everywhere where you are using `ourDatabase` variable

you can use something like following in constructor.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: Isn't that what `ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();` doing?

Comment: @user2450275 It should be `ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Answer (score 0):

```
    used this code in sq light java file


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class SQLiteAdapter {
    Cursor cursor;
    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Content1";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Content2";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT3 = "Content3";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT4 = "Content4";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT5 = "Content5";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT6 = "Content6";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT7 = "Content7";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT8 = "Content8";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT9 = "Content9";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT10 = "Content10";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT11 = "Content11";
    public static final String KEY_CONTENT12 = "Content12";

// create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE = "create table "
            + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_CONTENT1
            + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CONTENT3 + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT4
            + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT5 + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CONTENT6 + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT7
            + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT8 + " text not null, "
            + KEY_CONTENT9 + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT10
            + " text not null, " + KEY_CONTENT11 + " blob not null, "
            + KEY_CONTENT12 + "  long not null);";


    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);

        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
            db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```